# Button placed on the website Site.Master doesn't redirect when clicked from default.aspx, however button works from all other pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have added a search box on the Site.Master page of a website (ASP.NET) that I am developing using Visual Studio.

**Problem**
However I noticed that when I access default.aspx page and I click on the Search button it doesn't ReDirect (you may see below the code behind).  However when I access other pages of my website the button does redirect as required.

**Update**
I am noticing that all button on the default.apsx page are not raising postback on default.aspx page.... on the other pages. Buttons are working fine...

Code:

**SiteMaster**

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
                .......
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    ......
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    ......
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />


        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server">
                </asp:SiteMapPath>

            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">

   <div class="input-group">
     <asp:TextBox class="form-control" type="text" ID="tbSearch" width="100%" runat="server" placeholder="Search for recipes..."></asp:TextBox>

     <span class="input-group-btn">
    <asp:Button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search Recipes" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" ToolTip="Search Recipes" ValidateRequestMode="Disabled" />
     </span>
   </div>

                    </div>
               </div>  

            <br />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">


           .....     


</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**SiteMaster.cs**

In the Code behind I have the following code:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {
        private const string AntiXsrfTokenKey = "__AntiXsrfToken";
        private const string AntiXsrfUserNameKey = "__AntiXsrfUserName";
        private string _antiXsrfTokenValue;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // The code below helps to protect against XSRF attacks
            var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
            Guid requestCookieGuidValue;
            if (requestCookie != null && Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, out requestCookieGuidValue))
            {
                // Use the Anti-XSRF token from the cookie
                _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;
                Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
            }
            else
            {
                // Generate a new Anti-XSRF token and save to the cookie
                _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;

                var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
                };
                if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && Request.IsSecureConnection)
                {
                    responseCookie.Secure = true;
                }
                Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
            }

            Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
        }

        protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Set Anti-XSRF token
                ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] = Page.ViewStateUserKey;
                ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] = Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                // Validate the Anti-XSRF token
                if ((string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue
                    || (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] != (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.");
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        protected void Unnamed_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
        }

        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var searchText = Server.UrlEncode(tbSearch.Text); // URL encode in case of special characters
            Response.Redirect("~/Results.aspx?search=" + searchText);

        }
    }
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                Label2.Visible = true;
                Label1.Visible = false;
                tbPost.Visible = false;
                Button1.Visible = false;
            }

            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
                Label2.Visible = false;
                tbPost.Visible = true;
                Button1.Visible = true;

            }


            if (!this.IsPostBack) 
            {
                BindRpt();
            }

        }
```

Comment: I feel like this maybe something to do with the default.aspx page. Is there anything different between the default.aspx page and all the other pages?

Comment: I didnt notice anything different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was caused by an **input tag**....
So if any one of you will encounter this problem follow these steps:

1. Check any java script you have on the page
2. Check the page for any input tags:  -
   **When I added disable='' in the input tag, my problem was solved.**
3. You may also create a new page and copy to it parts of the code and check if it works correctly or not....

thats how I solved my problem